# Trying to understand the most simple Gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, groovy, gradle-plugin

Being new to Gradle and Groovy, I'm having a hard time understanding the following piece of code I came across in the [Writing a simple plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:writing_a_simple_plugin) tutorial:

```
class GreetingPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.task('hello') {
            doLast {
                println 'Hello from the GreetingPlugin'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. What is `project.task('hello') {...}`? It looks like a method declaration without a return type or like a method call with additional brackets... what is this construct?
2. What is `doLast {...}` and where does it originate from? What syntax pattern is that anyway... some keyword followed by brackets. I cannot find anything like it in the [Groovy syntax](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html) page, which mostly has examples of using `${}` or using brackets to define a class or method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In groovy, if the last argument to a method is a closure, you can put it outside the round brackets.

Eg

```
project.task('foo', {
    doStuff()
})
```

Is equivelant to

```
project.task('foo') {
    doStuff()
}
```

Here's the links to the javadocs for the two methods

1. [Project.task(String, Closure)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#task(java.lang.String,%20groovy.lang.Closure))
2. [Task.doLast(Closure)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#doLast(groovy.lang.Closure))

Comment: And if it only takes a Closure, you can drop the parentheses, hence `doLast { // stuff }` as the same as `doLast({ // stuff })`